# Set Secondary Color (ColorAccent) as Bottom Navigation Bar Background Color

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, material-design, user-experience

I am currently working on a cross platform mobile app using Xamarin forms. I also apply the Visual material in order to have a consistent UI between iOS and Android through Material design theme.

But I got a point I want some advices.
After choosing my color palette you can see a snapshot in this link : https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0&primary.color=039BE5&secondary.color=FFC107

For Navigation,  I had a bottom navigation bar and I set it its background color with the secondary color (the yellow one if you clicked on link above) .

Is it a good practice or the bottom navigation bar should be white or be colorPrimary of my Theme.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In order to enhance the user's visual effect and use experience, it is recommended that you use the colorPrimary of your Theme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I asked an UX designer colleague and she recommends me same like your comment. Thank you very much. Topic closed

Comment: Congrats,happy coding. :)

Comment: If I post it as a answer, could you mark it as a answer?